# How to access element in json using python?

Tags: python, json

I need help on how do I use python to access element from JSON structure.

Assuming I have a JSON like this

```
{
'result':
  [
    {
     'aa':1, 
     'bb':2
    },
    {
     'cc':3, 
     'dd':4
    }
  ]
 }
```

In python, how exactly to get the data for `aa` or `dd` ?
I tried with

```
str1 = {'result':[{'aa':1, 'bb':2},{'cc':3, 'dd':4}]}
str1new = str1['result']['aa]
```

but it gives me error

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I solve this? Is there any other method using python to get the data from JSON? Thank you for the help. I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this and for the next ones use indexes like 1 or 2 if you have more, or you can loop if you have multiple indexes within the `json`.

```
str1new = str1['result'][0]['aa']
```

Comment: there is a typo there but never mind. can you explain the index `[0]` there? what does it means?

Comment: well the 0 is for the index as you do in list or dictionary , you can see the starting [] which means its a index start

Comment: @Exprator `well the 0 is for the index as you do in list or dictionary`? Dictionary is not indexed.

Answer (score 2):

In python if you write:

```
str1 = {'result':[{'aa':1, 'bb':2},{'cc':3, 'dd':4}]}
```

it's dictionary and not json.

if your input is having json string you need to use

```
import json

json_str = """{
"result":
  [
    {
     "aa":1, 
     "bb":2
    },
    {
     "cc":3, 
     "dd":4
    }
  ]
 }"""
str1 = json.loads(json_str)
```

then you can use similar to python dictionary.

as answered by others you can then use

```
aa = str1['result'][0]['aa']
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
str1new = str1['result'][0]['aa]
```

Answer (score 1):

As `str1['result']` is a list, that's why you're getting `list indices must be integers, not str` error.

```
aa = str1['result'][0]['aa']
dd = str1['result'][1]['dd']
```

Comment: thank you. now I understand why it needs `[0]` or `[1]`in the answer based on your and others answer

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a list, so you need to reference a valid index before accessing `aa`:

```
str1 = {'result':[{'aa':1, 'bb':2},{'cc':3, 'dd':4}]}
str1new = str1['result'][0]['aa']
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, unless you're using a package (then specify it), "JSON" structure are actually dicts.

```
{
'result':
  [
    {
     'aa':1, 
     'bb':2
    },
    {
     'cc':3, 
     'dd':4
    }
  ]
 }
```

Here, your dict has only one key : `result`. Its values are contained in a list. This list is a list of dicts. So use cascade index access to get your `aa` value :

```
str1['result'][0]['aa']
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python3, using the Json library you can easily parse Json.

```
# import statement
import json

# using example sting from above
jsonString = '{ "result" : [{ "aa": 1,"bb": 2 }, { "cc": 3, "dd": 4 }]}'

# parse json string
parsedJsonObject = json.loads(jsonString)

# access a specific property in the json object 
resultObject = parsedJsonObject['result']
```